# Insert into database when onclick event in an image

Tags: php, image, onclick, href, insert-into

How could I do to make an onClick event in a href in an image? I've the following code:

**- infoproduct.php (html code)**

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="addfavourite()"><img src="img/favstar.png" width="32" height="32"></a></li>
```

**- function.php**

```
function addfavourite() {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `iduser` = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db_connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$newfav = 'INSERT INTO favourites (`iduser`,`idproduct`) VALUES ("'.$row['iduser'].'","'.$_GET['IDp'].'");';    //IDp = ID product obtained from URL
$createfav = mysql_query($newfav, $db_connection);
}
```

When I click on the image it doesn't work and I can't include my favourite product in the database. 
$_SESSION & $_GET works correctly and functions.php is included in infoproduct.php

I've also tried to put in html code onClick="addfavourite()**;**" but neither works.

Comment: You cannot run a PHP function from a click on a browser object. You ether need to write a javascript function called `addfavourite()` to call the PHP script or make the `href="function.php"`

Comment: This cannot work, you need to look into how JavaScript and PHP work. JavaScript is client-sided and has no visibility of the functions of PHP which is server-sided.

`onClick="addfavourite()"` will call a potential `addfavourite` function that is defined in JavaScript. If it isn't defined, then you are likely to see an error in your console.

The only way to trigger PHP execution with JavaScript is to use Ajax. I invite you to read tutorials about it.

Answer (score 1):

make a javascript function and call the php page having the function addfavourite() with the help of AJAX.
When the response is received as true, you can change the color of the button or star to yellow.

Comment: Thanks you! Could you show me and example, please? I've never used AJAX code and I've no idea... I want to make a product favourite and insert into my database clicking a yellow star, so I need when onClick event makes me this action.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are trying to do. What you have just done there is a combination of javascript and php however it is not the right way. Remember that javascript works with the front-end (browser and interface) and php is a back-end language. so you need a medium for them to communicate. I recommended that you use jquery/ json for this and assign an to the front-end. Check this:

**infoproduct.php**

```
<form action="infoproduct.php" method="POST">
<li><a href="#" name="id" onClick="addfavourite()"><img src="img/favstar.png" width="32" height="32"></a></li>

</form>
```

**OR**

**infoproduct.php**

```
  <li><a href="#" id="id" onClick="addfavourite()"><img src="img/favstar.png" width="32" height="32"></a></li>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#id').click(function(){
var id=$(this).val();

$.post('function.php',{id:id},function(data)
{
 alert(successfully)
})


});

});
</script> 

**function.php**

    <?php

    //Calling the function 
    addfavourite();

    function addfavourite() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `iduser` = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $db_connection);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $newfav = 'INSERT INTO favourites (`iduser`,`idproduct`) VALUES ("'.$row['iduser'].'","'.$_GET['IDp'].'");';    //IDp = ID product obtained from URL
    $createfav = mysql_query($newfav, $db_connection);


    }

    ?>
```